# Can I use blender to make construction plans for furniture I want to build?

Tags: export

I know I can use the metric measure unit.
What I want is some sort of export function to save all parts of the furniture as an image or PDF, containing all the metrics etc.

Can I use blender for that?

Comment: You could, but Blender isn't cut out to make it simple. You'd be much better off using CAD software instead.

Comment: ... agreed..Blender would be more suitable for visualizing the piece, _after_ the plans have been made.

Comment: Thx! Any recommendations for such a software?

Comment: A pricy solution would be AutoCAD by Autodesk, but maybe Google SketchUp does what you need, too.